# Как узнать параметры программы установленной на удаленном компе

Tags: windows, wmi, c#

Добрый день форумчане. Вожусь с сервером Windows 2008. Сервер представляет из себя кластер состоящий из двух компов. На два сервера установлена одна и та же программа с названием "Program" и она может одновременно функционировать только на одном из компов входящих в кластер. Необходимо с удаленного компа узнать на каком из компов в данное время она работает. Ну или хотя бы подскажите как давать вообще такой запрос на стационарном компе за которым сам работаю....Спасибо:)
я вот как даю запрос

```
string s = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_SoftwareElement WHERE Name=\"NameProgramm\"");
 ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(s);
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query); ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get(); 
foreach (ManagementObject cc in queryCollection)
 { Console.WriteLine(cc); }
```

попробовал как и советовали

```
string s = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name=\"NameProgramm\""); ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(s);
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query); ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
 foreach (ManagementObject cc in queryCollection) 
{ Console.WriteLine(cc); }
```

при пошаговой отработке на стадии ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get(); когда наводишь для того чтобы узнать значение пишет что "Время ожидания вычисления функции истекло"...и с моим вариантом и с вашим:( не знаю уже что делать

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой путь:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher installedSoft = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
       "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in installSoft.Get())
{
    //проверки на наличие program
}
```

Но: тут используется [Win32_Product](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156540.aspx) - enables you to enumerate the software installed on a computer, provided the software was installed by using the Windows Installer. Поэтому не стопроцентная гарантия что найдет.